# Retrieve User email using GTM OAuth2 for iOS

Tags: ios, google-api, oauth-2.0

I have successfully implemented authentication using GTM OAuth 2 library. But now I want to have the email id of the user. How should I proceed. I know I have to call something in here :-

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
             error:(NSError *)error {
if (error != nil) {

    NSLog(@"SIGN IN ERROR : %@", error.description);
    // Authentication failed
} else {
    // Authentication succeeded
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When signing in to Google services with gtm-oauth2, the user's email address is available after sign-in in the auth object's `userEmail` property.