# GTM OAuth 2.0 on iOS - retrieving user's email

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, gtm-oauth2, google-oauth

GTMOAuth 2.0 seems like an excellent tool for OAuth 2.0 verification on iOS.  I am trying to retrieve the full name and email of a Google user by implementing GTMOAuth-2 in Xcode but am having a bit of trouble.  Based on this answer: [Retrieve User email using GTM OAuth2 for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295055/retreive-user-email-using-gtm-oauth2-for-ios), it should be as easy as calling `auth.userEmail`.  However, the problem is that calling `auth.userEmail` in the following code segment always return `null`:

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth
             error:(NSError * )error
{
NSLog(@"finished");
NSLog(@"auth access token: %@", auth.accessToken);

[self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:NO];
if (error != nil) {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Authorizing with Google"
                                                     message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
} else {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success Authorizing with Google"
                                                     message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
NSLog(@"email: %@",auth.userEmail);
```

}

The code runs successfully and retrieves an access token, but `auth.userEmail` is always `null`.  Do I need to make a request to the Google email endpoint using GTMOAuth 2.0's `Fetcher` object, or otherwise send an additional HTTP GET request to retrieve the user's email using `auth.accessToken`?

Answer (score 0):

> I recently worked on `Google OAuth2` for logging user in with `gmail`
>   by following tutsplus's tutorial and It gave me the desired results.I
>   would recommend you to follow this link. This provides methods to
>   `login` and `logout` and also email address of logged in user. [Google
>   OAuth2](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/accessing-google-services-using-the-oauth-20-protocol--mobile-18394) 
>   . And to get email address of logged in user, add this in scopes
>   `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`. and code will look
>   like this

```
 [_googleOAuth authorizeUserWithClienID:@"YOUR CLIENT ID"
                           andClientSecret:@"SECRET"
                             andParentView:self.view
                                 andScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", nil]];
```

> And for GTM OAuth 2.0, add this
>   scope`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` .Hope this helps
>   you.